# Is the shared secret from ProtonMail SRP actually used for anything after logging in?

Tags: encryption, protonmail

Is this value just used to log in or is it used as a key for anything else later on? I see that the pm-srp code does make a point of keeping it around but it isn’t clear for what purpose, and some unofficial clients like Hydroxide don’t keep it at all.